# Class member visibility in member function declaration signature

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype, trailing-return-type

Why does this work:

```
template <typename A>
struct S {
    A a;
    template <typename B>
    auto f(B b) ->
        decltype(a.f(b))
    {
    }
};
```

But this does not (`a` and `f` swapped places):

```
template <typename A>
struct S {
    template <typename B>
    auto f(B b) ->
        decltype(a.f(b))
    {
    }
    A a;
};
```

saying that `a` is not declared in that scope (inside decltype) but adding explicit `this->` makes it work.

Comment: I know it's not the point of the question, but a good workaround would be `decltype(std::declval<A&>().f(b))`.

Comment: @yuri: My answer is informative, but I don't feel it's the best.  Please accept a different one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
template <typename A>
struct S {
    A a;
    template <typename B>
    auto f(B b) ->
        decltype(a.f(b))
    {
    }
};
```

This works because within a trailing return type, members of the surrounding class are visible. Not all members, but only the members that are declared prior to it (in a trailing return type, the class is *not* considered to be complete, as opposed to function bodies). So what is done here:

- As we are in a template, a lookup is done to see whether `a` is dependent or not. Since `a` was declared prior to `f`, `a` is found to refer to a class member.
- By the template rules in C++, it is found that `a` refers to a member of the current instantiation since it is a member of instantiations of the surrounding template. In C++, this notion is used mainly to decide whether names are dependent: If a name is known to refer to the surrounding template's members, it is not necessarily needed to be looked up when instantiating, because the compiler already knows the code of the template (which is used as the basis of the class type instantiated from it!). Consider:

  ```
  template<typename T>
  struct A {
    typedef int type;
    void f() {
      type x;
      A<T>::type y;
    }
  };
  ```

In C++03, the second line declaring `y` would be an error, because `A<T>::type` was a dependent name and needed a `typename` in front of it. Only the first line was accepted. In C++11, this inconsistency was fixed and both type names are non-dependent and won't need a `typename`. If you change the typedef to `typedef T type;` then both declarations, `x` and `y` will use a dependent type, but *neither* will need a `typename`, because you still name a member of the current instantiation and the compiler knows that you name a type.

- So `a` is a member of the current instantiation. But it is dependent, because the type used to declare it (`A`) is dependent. However this doesn't matter in your code. Whether dependent or not, `a` is found and the code valid.

---

```
template <typename A>
struct S {
    template <typename B>
    auto f(B b) ->
        decltype(a.f(b))
    {
    }
    A a;
};
```

In this code, again `a` is looked up to see whether it is dependent and/or whether it is a member of the current instantiation. But since we learned above that members declared after the trailing return type are not visible, we fail to find a declaration for `a`. In C++, besides the notion "member of the current instantiation", there is another notion:

- *member of an unknown specialization*. This notion is used to refer to the case where a name might instead refer to a member of a class that depends on template parameters. If we had accessed `B::a`, then the `a` would be a member of an unknown specialization because it is *unknown* what declarations will be visible when `B` is substituted at instantiation.
- *neither a member of the current, nor a member of an unknown specialization.* This is the case for all other names. *Your case fits here*, because it is known that `a` can never be a member of any instantiation when instantiation happens (remember that name lookup cannot find `a`, since it is declared after `f`).

Since `a` is not made dependent by any rule, the lookup that did not find any declaration is *binding*, meaning there is no other lookup at instantiation that could find a declaration. Non-dependent names are lookup up at template definition time. Now GCC rightfully gives you an error (but note that as always, an ill-formed template is not required to be diagnosed immediately).

---

```
template <typename A>
struct S {
    template <typename B>
    auto f(B b) ->
        decltype(this->a.f(b))
    {
    }
    A a;
};
```

In this case, you added `this` and GCC accepted. The name `a` that follows `this->` again is lookup at to see whether it might be a member of the current instantiation. But again because of the member visibility in trailing return types, no declaration is found. Hence the name is deemed not to be a member of the current instantiation. Since there is no way that at instantiation, `S` could have additional members that `a` could match (there are no base classes of `S` that depend on template parameters), the name is also not a member of an unknown specialization.

Again C++ has no rules to make `this->a` dependent. However it uses `this->`, so the name *must* refer to some member of `S` when it is instantiated! So the C++ Standard says

> Similarly, if the id-expression in a class member access expression for which the type of the object expression is the current instantiation does not refer to a member of the current instantiation or a member of an unknown specialization, the program is ill-formed even if the template containing the member access expression is not instantiated; no diagnostic required.

Again no diagnostic is required for this code (and GCC actually doesn't give it). The id-expression `a` in the member access expression `this->a` was dependent in C++03 because the rules in that Standard were not as elaborated and fine-tuned as in C++11. For a moment let's imagine C++03 had `decltype` and trailing return types. What would this mean?

- The lookup would have been delayed until instantiation, because `this->a` would be dependent
- The lookup at instantiation of, say, `S<SomeClass>` would fail, because `this->a` would not be found at instantiation time (as we said, trailing return types do not see members declared later).

Hence, the early rejection of that code by C++11 is good and useful.

Comment: "If we had accessed B::a, then the a would be a member of an unknown specialization"... Surely you mean if we had accessed `S<B>::a` ?

Comment: @BenVoigt if `B` will be a class and `a` a static data member, then it could work when instantiated :) I meant to talk about some random other scenario he could be having. Of course, `S<B>::a` would also work and could be valid depending on what `B` is when instantiating.

Answer (score 2):

The body of a member function is compiled as if it was defined after the class. Therefore everything declared in the class is in scope at that point.

However, the declaration of the function is still inside the class declaration  and can only see names that precede it.

```
template <typename A>
struct S {
    template <typename B>
    auto f(B b) ->
        decltype(a.f(b)); // error - a is not visible here

    A a;
};

template <typename A>
template <typename B>
    auto S<A>::f(B b) ->
        decltype(a.f(b))
    {
        return a.f(b);   // a is visible here
    }
```

Comment: Okay, then how does adding `this->` work? Does it postpone name resolution until after the class body is parsed?

Comment: @BenVoigt: If the `this->` thing works, don't things like http://ideone.com/AThdkE allow infinite self-references?

Comment: @Ben `this->f` is not a dependent name in his case because he has no dependent base classes (and although `this` is type-dependent, that does not make `this->f` dependent in C++11).

Comment: @Johannes: That's what I thought aswell, but the quote Ben's answer suggests otherwise.

Comment: @Xeo: Well, there's "Is `a` found in `this->a`?" and "Can I write `declspec(this->a(f))` there?"  And the answers appear to be Yes and No respectively.

Comment: @aschepler: I think g++ (ideone version) is rejecting that for the wrong reason.  See the bolded quote in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The Standard says (section 14.6.2.1):

> If, for a given set of template arguments, a specialization of a template is instantiated that refers to a member of the current instantiation with a qualified-id or class member access expression, the name in the qualified-id or class member access expression is looked up in the template instantiation context.

`this->a` is a class-member access expression, therefore this rule applies and lookup takes place at the point of instantiation, where <strike>`S<A>` is complete</strike>.

---

Finally, this doesn't solve your problem at all, because section 5.1.1 says:

> If a declaration declares a member function or member function template of a class X, **the expression `this` is a prvalue of type “pointer to *cv-qualifier-seq* `X`” between the optional *cv-qualifier-seq* and the end of the *function-definition*, *member-declarator*, or *declarator***. It shall not appear before the optional *cv-qualifier-seq*
> and it shall not appear within the declaration of a static member function (although its type and value category are defined within a static member function as they are within a non-static member function).

So you can't use `this->` here, since it is before the *cv-qualifier-seq* part of the function declaration.

Wait, no it isn't!  Section 8.4.1 says

> The declarator in a *function-definition* shall have the form
>
> `D1  (` *`parameter-declaration-clause`*`)` *`cv-qualifier-seq opt ref-qualifier opt exception-specification opt attribute-specifier-seq opt trailing-return-type opt`*

Comment: Now, if you'd add a quote / explanation on why the second snippet doesn't work as-is... :) (`§9.2/2`)

Comment: You have a crucial error. "this->a is a class-member access expression, therefore this rule applies and lookup takes place at the point of instantiation, where S<A> is complete." -> the name is looked up in *both* the instantiation and the definition context (even if it is a non-dependent name). That is the purpose of that paragraph. If the lookup results differ, the program is ill-formed.

Comment: Your last "However" addition is incorrect aswell, because a non-static member function is not a non-static data member.

Comment: @Johannes: Thanks, fixed the however.  The important rule was in the previous paragraph.

Comment: @Johannes: I think you're wrong about the other point though.  The rule says "Such names are unbound and are looked up at the point of the template instantiation in both the context of the template definition and the context of the point of instantiation."  That means for example that `*this << t;` would search for `operator<<` in the namespace where the class is as well as the namespace where the instantiation is.  But it will NOT be looked up during first phase.

Comment: How about http://ideone.com/sJJFAC ?  Avoids the `this` issue, but I still think there must be some rule that future class member declarations can't be visible when determining the type (not initializer/definition) of a member declaration.

Comment: @aschepler: Ditto http://ideone.com/aMSQmg  Which carries a much more explanatory diagnostic (it is a dependent name, the lookup occurs for `X<int>` specifically, but it's still an incomplete type there).

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice that `A a;` uses the template parameter `A`. I thought it is like `std::string a;`. But that doesn't change that this program is invalid because of 14.6.2.1p6: *Similarly, if the id-expression in a class member access expression for which the type of the object expression is the current instantiation does not refer to a member of the current instantiation or a member of an unknown specialization, the program is ill-formed even if the template containing the member access expression is not instantiated; no diagnostic required.*.

Comment: @BenVoigt in `*this << t`, we have "If an operand of an operator is a type-dependent expression, the operator also denotes a dependent name." (`t`). However for our `this->a`, we have no such rule that makes `this->a` dependent. Note that this is entirely logical, because the compiler when parsing the member knows that if it would instantiate the code, it would look into the surrounding scope, and the surrounding scope would not be affected by instantiation semantics (because there are no dependent base classes). So the rules in C++11 actually reflects the desired semantics quite well.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: But it does refer to a member of the current instantiation, so I don't see that rule being a problem.

Comment: @BenVoigt no it does not refer to a member of the current instantiation because in trailing return types, the surrounding class type is still incomplete (see the note at the end of 5.1.1p3). Hence the name does not "refer to at least one member of the current instantiation or a non-dependent base class thereof."

Comment: @Johannes: I think I see what you're getting at about `this->a` not being a dependent name.  With dependent base classes, it would be "a member of an unknown specialization" (14.6.2.1p5).  And that makes it a dependent name (14.6.2.1p8).  It is instead "a member of the current specialization", which is not a dependent name.

Comment: @BenVoigt yes with dependent base classes it is a member of an unknown specialization and that would make it dependent by 14.6.2.2p5. As it is now, it is neither a member of the current, nor a member of an unknown specialization. And hence, 14.6.2.1p6 applies and the template/program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required. If you put the declaration `A a;` before the member function template, then `this->a` is a member of the current instantiation, and 14.6.2.2p5 would make it dependent because it is "a member of the current
instantiation and the type of the referenced member is dependent".

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Oh, it is a member of the current specialization in the first code sample.  In the second code sample, phase-one lookup fails, so it is then not a member of the current specialization.  That right?

Comment: I posted an explanation in my answer of this.